# What are these holes in my frame for?

Tags: frames, specialized-bikes

I have two threaded holes on the inside of my frame on my 2007 Stumpjumper FSR and I don't know what they are for.

[image]

Can anyone tell me why they're there?

Comment: It just occurred to me that they might be there to mount a remote valve for a brain shock or something...

Comment: I've already used my quota of flippant comments today :-)

Answer (score 6):

That's the mount for the Flow Control valve on the Specialized AFR Shock.

The shocks with flow valves came stock on the higher end models of the 2007 Stumpjumper FSR like the Expert, Pro and the S-Works Carbon frame:

[image]